# R dyplr left_join inside a function not working

Tags: r, rstudio, tidyverse

I'm trying to create a function with the left_join operator that replicates this:

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  name = c("John", "Paul", "George", "Ringo", "Stuart", "Pete"),
  instrument = c("guitar", "bass", "guitar", "drums", "bass",
                 "drums"),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
df2 <- data.frame(
  name2 = c("John", "Paul", "George", "Ringo", "Brian"),
  band = c("TRUE", "TRUE", "TRUE", "TRUE", "FALSE"),stringsAsFactors=FALSE) 

z <- left_join(df1, df2, by = c("name" = "name2"))
```

This works as expected, however if I create a function like this:

```
left <- function(x,y,id1) {
  left_join(x, y, by = c(id1 = "name2"))
}

left(df1,df2,name)
```

Now I get an error:

```
Error: `by` can't contain join column `id1` which is missing from LHS
```

I have been playing with bang bang, quo operators and !! but I'm not able to make it work passing id1 as an argument.

Note: This is a simplification of a piping (%>%) process but the main issue is not being able to call id1 inside the c() function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `setNames`

```
left <- function(x, y, id1) {
    left_join(x, y, by = setNames("name2", id1))
}

left(df1, df2, "name")
#    name instrument band
#1   John     guitar TRUE
#2   Paul       bass TRUE
#3 George     guitar TRUE
#4  Ringo      drums TRUE
#5 Stuart       bass <NA>
#6   Pete      drums <NA>
```